# Problem regarding relative velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, velocity, relative-motion

Train A moves north with speed 54km/h. What is the velocity of a monkey running on roof of a train A against its motion (with velocity of 18km/h with respect to A)as observed by a man standing on ground(in m/s)?

Velocity of Monkey with respect to ground is – VM

Velocity of Monkey with respect to train A is - VMA

Relative velocity of Monkey with respect to train A - VMA

VMA = VM - VA

Given - Velocity of Monkey with respect to train A = VA = 54 Km/h = 54 x 5/18 m/s = 15 m/s

And Relative velocity of Monkey with respect to train A = VMA = -18 Km/h = -18 x 5/18 = -5 m/s

(as monkey running against the motion)

Therefore,

VMA = VM - VA

-5 m/s = VM – 15 m/s

VM = -5 m/s + 15 m/s

VM = 10 m/s

QUESTION :
Why is VM positive? Shouldn't it be negative as it is moving opposite to the direction of the train?

Answer (score 1):

The question implied that velocity is measured relative to the train track as the reference frame. Therefore the monkey's velocity is positive in the reference frame. It is -5 m/s in the train frame, which is not the reference frame here.

Comment: Yes, the train track is taken to be the frame of reference. But in the frame of reference, we're considering the velocity of the train to be positive, and since the monkey is running against its motion, the velocity of the monkey should be negative according to me. Shouldn't it be -10 m/s in that case?

Comment: As I have said, it is only in the train frame where the monkey's velocity is negative, not in the reference frame (the track), where it is +10 m/s, just as your calculation shows.

Comment: If a reference frame is not implied in the problem statement, one is free to choose any frame as reference, but then it is wise to express all vectors relative to that frame. Mixing reference frames is never a good idea, unless the question is about  transforming vectors from one frame to another one.

Comment: in your question, a reference frame wa given by "as observed by a man standing on ground" if the tran moves to the right the man on the ground sees the monkey moving tu the right, so positiv v